# problem on adding ssh key to github - permission denied

Tags: linux, github, ssh

I generated the `SSH` key using the command:  `$ ssh-keygen`, It prompted for a filename and phrase, which I provided and generated the corresponding file. Then from `github.com` I added the `SSH` key from `settings>SSH and GPG keys` where I pasted the key in the generated file. Then I hit the command `$ ssh -T git@github.com` in the terminal which gave me a :`Permission denied (publickey).` message. What does this message mean and why am I getting this? Previously I didn't have trouble with this.

Answer (score 2):

> where I pasted the key in the generated file.

Make sure it was:

- the id_rsa.pub file, meaning the public key (not the private one)
- the public key pasted as *one* continuous line (not multiple lines)

Check also you have [added your private key to the ssh-agent](http://%20where%20I%20pasted%20the%20key%20in%20the%20generated%20file.). (in order to not enter the passphrase every time)